# XSD: Getting error while loading XSD file

Tags: xml, scala, xsd, databricks, xsd-validation

```scala
val schemaParsed = XSDToSchema.read(Paths.get("/FileStore/tables/file.xsd"))
```

It is giving me an error `FileNotFoundException: /FileStore/tables/file.xsd (No such file or directory)`

But I have stored this .xsd file in this dir.already

any suggestion ?

[image]

[image: "DBFS File browser enabled"]

[image: "Error"]

Comment: The slash (/) at the beginning means your folder „FileStore“ is at the root of your file system. Is that the case?

Comment: if it is the DBFS path - maybe try with "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/file.xsd"

Comment: @rainingdistros I tried using dbfs:/ but same error.

Comment: Just for trying - Enable the file browser as show in the link - https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/workspace/dbfs-browser.html Once done - Click on Data on the left panel (above Compute and Workflows) -> Click on DBFS (just below the search bar) -> Navigate to the file - FileStore/tables/. Once there Click the drop down and `Copy path` - Try with both the options

Comment: @rainingdistros
Please look at the attached screenshorts . I have followed all these instructions But getting same error.

Comment: your attached screenshot is checking for a different file name from the one mentioned in the Paths.get() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the existence of the file

[image]

Read the file as shown in the spark-xml github page.

```scala
import com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema
import java.nio.file.Paths

val schemaParsed = XSDToSchema.read(Paths.get("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/xsd/purchase_order_sample.xsd"))
print(schemaParsed)
```

Please note that when used within the code, the dbfs path is mentioned as `/dbfs/` instead of `dbfs:/` Please go through the [link](https://docs.databricks.com/files/index.html#understand-default-locations-with-examples) to understand further...

[image]

Comment: I maybe wrong, but just an easy way for me to remember - when used within python/scala code - I use /dbfs and when used within pyspark or spark-scala code I use dbfs:/ - not technically correct, but I just use it as an easy way to remember.